# Native app for iPhone!

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I want to develop a native universal app(i.e for iPhone and iPad) for my orgaization.I want to include some of the essential features of the organiztion website into my native app.For obvious reasons i cant store this huge data into iPhone itself.so data will be fetched from the server but application would be a native app.so are there any APIs available to do this?

Comment: The reasons aren't obvious at all. What kind of data is it, how big is it, and how would you plan to use it on the iPhone form factor?

Comment: Yes there are loads of APIs for getting website data but it sounds like you are at a very low-level of knowledge of programming the Iphone that it would be pointless going through them as you wouldn't understand them at the moment.

Comment: @Marcelo..dat includes lots of videos,podcasts,images etc

Comment: @Robert..yes Robert i am a beginner...but got a challenging job to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always find it's easier to start using sample code, and lucky for you Apple provides a lot of this.  Here is the reference library for all kinds of goodies to learn off of and hack your way through:  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code

A few noted ones... (I left out some advanced ones like `BonjourWeb` `Reachability` and `AdvancedURLConnections` but look at those once you gain a little more understanding)

URL Cache: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/URLCache/Introduction/Intro.html

RSS Feed Parser: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html

MailComposer: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html

Also, a couple books you should get to start your journey on iOS (these are two of the best and easy to understand IMO):

http://apress.com/book/view/9781430224594

http://apress.com/book/view/9781430225058

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` will show any web page you point it to.

Maybe do a mixed approach with some stuff built right into the app, and the bigger or frequently changing parts load from the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIWebView` to access your organization's website from inside a native application...

Comment: Yes, but what's the point?  The iPhone already has an application that will display a web view of an arbitrary web page.  It's called "Safari".  I think the questioner actually wants to be able to download data so that his app can be used if off-line or outside the company firewall.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that you may need to do your research first, the IPhone/Ipad SDK includes a very easy to use XML parser (NSXMLParser). I would suggest you devise a XML web service for retrieving the data from your company's servers and parse it on the ipad/iphone to the presentation you require.

Best of luck, i've found objective-c very rewarding/challenging.